# Десериализация внешних обьектов!

Tags: java, сериализация, bytearray, unserialize

Вопрос заключается в следующем. Есть некий внешний обьект, который присылает на определенный порт пакет байтовых значений (примитивы и обьект(в котором тоже либо примитивы, либо список обьектов)), сам код, который присылает написан на С.
Мне надо на Java поймать этот пакет(это я сделал), и преобразовать массив этих байтов в обьект, ну и в последствии с ними работать. Вопрос как это сделать, стандартная Десериализация не работает.
Выпадает illegalargumentexception failed to deserialize object
Написал клиента который собирает такой обьект -> переводит в байт[] -> все работает. 
А ну известен порядок данных и размер.

```
    byte[] sync = new byte[8];
    byte[] dataIn = new byte[3824];
    byte[] crc = new byte[8];
    int j = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++){
        int switchVariable = 0;
        if( i < 8) switchVariable = 1;
        else if(i < 3834) switchVariable = 2;
        else if(i < 3844) switchVariable = 3;
        switch (switchVariable){
            case (1):{
                sync[j] = bytes[i]; j++;
                break;
            }
            case (2):{ if(i == 3834) j = 0;
                dataIn[j] = bytes[i]; j++;
                break;
            }
            case (3):{ if(i == 3844) j = 0;
                crc[j] = bytes[i]; j++;
                break;
            }
        }

    }
    OutputObject outputObject = new OutputObject();
        outputObject.setSynchronization((byte) new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(sync)).read());
        outputObject.setData((byte[]) new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(dataIn)).readObject());
        outputObject.setCrc32(new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(crc)).read());
```

Answer (score 2):

Надо написать собственный десериализатор (это не так сложно как может показаться).

Надо всего лишь написать класс наследние `InputStream`, который имплементирует интерфейс  `ObjectInput`, по сути там всего несколько методов `read(), readObject(), skip()`. Если вы знаете сдвижки и длины байтов, то написать не составит особого труда.

Далее уже читаете свои объекты типа:

```
MyObjectInputStream objectInputStream =
new MyObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayStream(buffer));

MyClass object = (MyClass) objectInputStream.readObject();
```